# AppleScript to force quit Java (JAR) programs?

Tags: java, macos, process, applescript, activity-monitor

**Hello,**

I run a Java (jar) application on MAC OS. I am using an AppleScript to run the Java program and it works fine. Now, I like to use an AppleScript to close the Java program. I need to ***Force Quit*** the Java program. I used the following AppleScript,

```
set app_name to "NPC"
set the_pid to (do shell script "ps ax | grep " & (quoted form of app_name) & " | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'")
if the_pid is not "" then do shell script ("kill -9 " & the_pid)
```

The AppleScript that runs the Java program is called "NPC.app" When I run "NPC.app" it shows as **NPC** and **NPC.npc** on the Activity Monitor application. The above code which is set to remove the NPC application does not remove either **NPC** (this is the "NPC.app") or **NPC.npc** (this is the Java program). I get the following error,

> error "sh: line 0: kill: 1180 1182: arguments must be process or job
>   IDs" number 1

1180 being the PID for **NPC** and 1182 being the PID for **NPC.npc** in the Activity Monitor.

What is the correct AppleScript to force quit the Java program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the AppleScript that will close Java programs,

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do shell script "ps ax | grep \"java.*$1\" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print \"kill \" $1 }' | sh"
    quit
end tell
```

*Reference: [MAC OS - Is there a way to close a Java program?](http://answers.bitrock.com/questions/3707/mac-os-is-there-a-way-to-close-a-java-program#_=_)

*Thanks to: wojciechka ♦♦**

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pkill` instead:

```
do shell script ("pkill -9 NPC*")
```

Some examples [here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/10/18/kill-process-wildcards-pkill-mac-os-x/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I go the following error message when I tried it: "The command exited with a non-zero status." number 1

Comment: What happens if you try running it by hand from a Terminal window? Also, try some different signal numbers.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I am still working on it. But I will reply to you in a day or two.

Comment: Whoever downvoted my reply, it would be nice if you had the courtesy to explain why...

Comment: It was not me Mark. I am still working on the script with my program.