# How do I make my Java application apple-scriptable

Tags: java, swing, cocoa, applescript

I want to be able to set properties and commands for my Java Swing app. Similar questions have either [deferred to using shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900013/applescript-to-force-quit-java-jar-programs) or [remain unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504224/creating-an-applescript-interface-in-a-java-application). Looks like [normally this is done in Cocoa](https://macosxautomation.com/applescript/develop/index.html). Does this mean I need to incorporate Cocoa into my project just to be able to command it through AppleScript? Currently, I cannot even do simple commands such as resizing windows (which I wrongly assumed would work out of the box).

Comment: I think this is the best [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/Concepts/scriptable_apps.html) to go with

Comment: At some point there was fairly close integration between Java and Cocoa which made this sort of thing achievable by Apple-supplied and supported mechanisms. As things stand now, a pure Java app does not have easy access to OS X automation technologies.

Comment: Java usually provides no support for a not cross-platform functionality.

Comment: I was worried this wouldn't be easy. Thanks for the responses.